# using same directory created on isolated storage across multiple pages or xaml

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I am using three xaml pages in one solution. I have created directory named as "Storage" in xaml1. I need to use the same directory across other two xaml....

code:

```
 using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
 {
   myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("Storage");
   IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Storage\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
   { }
 }
```

How to use this directory in other two xaml's?

Any help.....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, what is the problem? Have you tried using the same code in the other xaml pages?

Comment: "Storage" is the file name.You can retrieve the file "storage" any where within current project in isolated storage.If u want to store another file store in another name in myfile.

Answer (score 2):

just check if the directory exists, and then use the same code to work with it:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
 {

   if(!myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists("Storage")) return;
   if(!myIsolatedStorage.FileExists("Storage\\myFile.txt")) return;
   var fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Storage\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   using (StreamReader writer = new StreamReader(fileStream))
   { }
 }
```

IsolatedStorage is one for the application, not for the page.
Some details and examples [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---File-manipulations).